# Xcode is not running OpenGL with most up to date version, which is causing compilation errors

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

I am using OpenGL and GLSL. I am following a tutorial, this one to be exact: [Exact video of tutorial that I am having problem with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLUtSE2osfI&list=PLSPw4ASQYyymu3PfG9gxywSPghnSMiOAW&index=10) but he does not use xcode, which is what I am using, and it has lead to this issue.

I'll start this out with my system information, and all the information I think is relevant enough to share that'll help with the problem. I will then tell you what the problem is, along with everything else I've learned that I think is relevant and helpful. After that, I'll include a copy of all the code I used, so you can look at it for errors and the real problem and such.

**System Information:**

iMac (21.5 inch, mid-2011)
OS X Yosesemite (V 10.10.1)

Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Graphics:
OpenGL version: 4.1 ATI-1.28.29
GLSL version: 4.10
Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 6750M OpenGL Engine

Xcode v 6.1.1

**My problem:**

The problem is that Shader is failing to compile.

fragment-shader.txt:

```
#version 130

out vec3 color;

void main() {

color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

}
```

vertex-shader.txt

```
#version 130

in vec2 vertexPosition;

void main() {
    //Set the x,y position on the screen
    gl_Position.xy = vertexPosition;
    //the z position is zero since we are in 2D
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;

    //Indicate that the coordinates are normalized
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

Both of these fail to compile. The compilation call will be in GLSLProgram.cpp, more specifically void GLSLProgram::compileShader.

I do check for errors, and the error message I recieved was: "ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported"

The typical causes of this error I discovered is an outdated graphics card. I know that this is not the case, However, I checked anyways, just during runtime. I check my OpenGl version and glsl version, and I get the following result:

OpenGL version: 2.1 ATI-1.28.29
GLSL version: 1.20
Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 6750M OpenGL Engine

It is reading my memory card, but the OpenGL and GLSL version are wrong. I have no idea why. And I have been unable to figure out why or how to fix it myself through the internet, and that is why I am here.

I downloaded a random crossplatform program that also uses GLSL, and it runs fine. I'm not really familiar with openGL, so I wasn't able to look at the code and figure out what the problem was. All I can do is give my best educated guess. I think it is a preprocessor error. I might be using the incorrect preprocessor, or an outdated version, or I don't know. That's the problem. The code that worked however, printed out the correct the OpenGL version and GLSL version during runtime. So I do know something is causing me not to use the most up to date version. I dont know if that is the only problem, but I do know that is one of the problems.

The code I mentioned in previous paragraph is from [this tutorial](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/01-getting-started-in-xcode-and-visual-cpp/), and access to the code is in a link in the first paragraph of that tutorial

**Code**

I'm on only going to include the cpp files. Forward declarations are in the header file, but I dont see the need to include them. If you do in fact need them, ask, and I will post them.

main.cpp

```
#include "MainGame.h"
#include "Sprite.h"

#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv) {
    MainGame mainGame;
    mainGame.run();

    return 0;
}
```

MainGame.cpp     (Ties everything together)

```
#include "MainGame.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>



MainGame::MainGame(){
    _window = nullptr;
    _screenHeight = 768;
    _screenWidth = 1024;
    _gameState = PLAY;
}

MainGame::~MainGame(){

}

void MainGame::run(){
    initSystems();


    _sprite.init(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    gameLoop();
}

void MainGame::initSystems(){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    _window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, _screenWidth, _screenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (_window == nullptr) {
        fatalError("SDL Window could not be created. :(");
    }

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window);
    if (glContext == nullptr) {
        fatalError("SDL_GL context could not be created. :(");
    }

    std::cout << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLSL version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vendor: " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Renderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;


    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0);




    initShaders();

}


void MainGame::initShaders(){
    _colorProgram.compileShaders("/Users/user/filepath.../vertex-shader.txt", "/Users/user/filepath.../fragment-shader.txt");
    _colorProgram.addAttribute("vertexPosition");
    _colorProgram.linkShaders();
}


void MainGame::gameLoop(){
    while (_gameState != GameState::EXIT) {
        processInput();
        drawGame();
    }
}


void MainGame::processInput(){
    SDL_Event evnt;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&evnt))
        switch (evnt.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                _gameState = EXIT;
                break;

            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                std::cout << evnt.motion.x << " " << evnt.motion.y << std::endl;
                break;
        }
}


void MainGame::drawGame(){
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    _colorProgram.use();

    _sprite.draw();

    _colorProgram.unuse();

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_window);

}
```

GLSLProgram.cpp     (Handles most GLSL related things)

```
#include "GLSLProgram.h"
#include "Errors.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>



GLSLProgram::GLSLProgram() : _numAttributes(0), _programID(0), _vertexShaderID(0), _fragmentShaderID(0)
{

}

GLSLProgram::~GLSLProgram(){

}

void GLSLProgram::compileShaders(const std::string& vertexShaderFilePath, const std::string& fragmentShaderFilePath){
    _vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    if (_vertexShaderID == 0){
        fatalError("Vertex Shader failed to be created");
    }

    _fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    if (_fragmentShaderID == 0){
        fatalError("Fragment Shader failed to be created");
    }

    compileShader(vertexShaderFilePath, _vertexShaderID);

    compileShader(fragmentShaderFilePath, _fragmentShaderID);


}



void GLSLProgram::addAttribute(const std::string& attributeName){
    glBindAttribLocation(_programID, _numAttributes++, attributeName.c_str());
}



void GLSLProgram::linkShaders(){
    //Vertex and fragment shaders are successfully compiled.
    //Now time to link them together into a program.
    //Get a program object.
    _programID = glCreateProgram();

    //Attach our shaders to our program
    glAttachShader(_programID, _vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(_programID, _fragmentShaderID);

    //Link our program
    glLinkProgram(_programID);

    //Note the different functions here: glGetProgram* instead of glGetShader*.
    GLint isLinked = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(_programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int *)&isLinked);
    if(isLinked == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(_programID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        //The maxLength includes the NULL character
        std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_programID, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);

        //We don't need the program anymore.
        glDeleteProgram(_programID);
        //Don't leak shaders either.
        glDeleteShader(_vertexShaderID);
        glDeleteShader(_fragmentShaderID);

        std::printf("%s/n", &(errorLog[0]));
        fatalError("Shaders failed to link");        //In this simple program, we'll just leave


    }

    //Always detach shaders after a successful link.
    glDetachShader(_programID, _vertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(_programID, _fragmentShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(_vertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(_fragmentShaderID);

}






void GLSLProgram::use(){
    glUseProgram(_programID);
    for (int i = 0; i < _numAttributes; i++) {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    }
}



void GLSLProgram::unuse(){
    glUseProgram(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < _numAttributes; i++) {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(i);
    }
}







void GLSLProgram::compileShader(const std::string& filePath, GLuint id){
    std::ifstream shaderFile(filePath);
    if (shaderFile.fail()){
        perror(filePath.c_str());
        fatalError("Failed to open " + filePath);
    }

    std::string fileContents ="";
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(shaderFile, line)) {
        fileContents += line + "\n";
    }

    shaderFile.close();



    const char* contentsPtr = fileContents.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &contentsPtr, nullptr);


    glCompileShader(id);

    GLint success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);


    if(success == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        // The maxLength includes the NULL character
        std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);

        // Provide the infolog in whatever manor you deem best.
        // Exit with failure.
        glDeleteShader(id); // Don't leak the shader.


        std::printf("%s\n", &(errorLog[0]));
        fatalError("Shader " + filePath + " failed to compile");
    }

    // Shader compilation is successful.


}
```

Sprite.cpp     (Draws a simple triangle)

```
#include "Sprite.h"



Sprite::Sprite(){
    _vboID = 0;
}


Sprite::~Sprite(){
    if (_vboID != 0){
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vboID);
    }
}


void Sprite::init(float x, float y, float width, float height){
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    _width = width;
    _height = height;

    if (_vboID == 0){
        glGenBuffers(1, &_vboID);
    }

    float vertexData[12];

    //first triangle
    vertexData[0] = x + width;
    vertexData[1] = y + height;

    vertexData[2] = x;
    vertexData[3] = y + height;

    vertexData[4] = x;
    vertexData[5] = y;

    //second triangle
    vertexData[6] = x + width;
    vertexData[7] = y + height;

    vertexData[8] = x;
    vertexData[9] = y;

    vertexData[10] = x + width;
    vertexData[11] = y;

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}


void Sprite::draw(){
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}
```

error.cpp (quits in case of error)

```
#include "Errors.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>


void fatalError(std::string errorString) {
    std::cout << errorString << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter any key to quit...";
    int tmp;
    std::cin >> tmp;
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Additionally, this code does work, on Windows at least. Almost all of it was taken from the youtube link above, just with slight modifications to work with Xcode. There is a link to that code in the description of the youtube vid.

Comment: I think you specifically have to create an OpenGL context with support for OpenGL 4 (or the minimum version which you need).

Comment: See this link for how to do it with SDL: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial1:_Creating_a_Cross_Platform_OpenGL_3.2_Context_in_SDL_(C_/_SDL)

Comment: Ok. That Makes a lot of sense. When I have time tonight, I'll try and do that. Thank you for the response.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. You just need a core profile context on OS X if you don't want an OpenGL 2.1 context at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call SDL_GL_SetAttribute before creating the window to set the minimal OpenGL version you expect.

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
```

Comment: Ok, so I confirmed the minimum version I needed, and it was indeed 3.0. I Put the code in after SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING), and right before the window was made.  But now SDL_GLContext = nullptr, (This wasn't happening before, it was set to something other than that which meant it was working) I don't know if the shaders were compiled, the program doesn't make it that far when I comment out the errors that made it end.

Comment: That's not going to work. OS X doesn't support OpenGL 3.0. It supports 2.1, 3.2,3.3 and 4.1 (depending on operating system version). But to get anything other than 2.1, you need a core profile.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman according to the docs I found the `GL_SetAttribute` were minimums

Comment: @ratchetfreak: That's true, but the problem here is how OS X handles context versions. It does not implement a 3.0 context, it jumps straight from 2.1 (legacy) to 3.2 (core). You won't get that 3.2 context if you don't request core. And some frameworks are really picky about this and won't give you a core profile unless you request 3.2 forward-compatible exactly (_e.g._ GLFW).